# fetch remote branch with the same name

Tags: git, remote-branch

I want to fetch a branch from a remote, but my branch name does not start with remote name, for example:

```
git checkout -b BRANCH origin/BRANCH
```

It work in some cases, but in some cases I get this error:

```
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
```

while i am sure that the remote has this branch, and this works:

```
git checkout -b origin/BRANCH
```

After that, I have to switch to another branch and rename branch origin/BRANCH to BRANCH, and then switch to BRANCH again...
I want to know what that error means.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is why you are getting the error message that you are.

`git checkout` can do one of two things. If you just specify a branch and don't specify any paths then it will switch your current branch to the branch that you specified.

```
git checkout mybranch   # switch to branch 'my branch'
```

If you supply some paths, then git will checkout those paths either from the index or, if you specify a branch, from a given branch.

```
git checkout myfile   # checkout 'myfile' from index
```

As you can see, there is a potential ambiguity. What should happen if you had a branch called `myfile` or a file called `mybranch`?

The way that git resolves this ambiguity is that it tests the parameter to see whether it matches a branch first, and if not it assumes that the parameter refers to a file. If you had a branch and file with the same name you can force git to treat the parameter as a file with this syntax.

```
git checkout -- myfile  # treat 'myfile' as a file
```

The `-b` option, which creates a new branch, is only valid when you are using the branch switching form of `checkout` and not when you are checking out specified files from the index.

```
git checkout -b newbranch myfile  # Illegal. I can't use `-b` when
                                  # I'm checking out files.
```

If you try `git checkout -b newbranch origin/BRANCH` and you get this error it means that `origin/BRANCH` didn't match the name of any branch that you have so git assumed that you must be referring to a file.

To show what remote branch references you have you can do `git branch -r`. If you don't have a reference to a branch that you think should exist you may have to perform a `git fetch` to retrieve it from the remote.

If you supply `-b` but no branch name to base the new branch off, git defaults to using `HEAD`, i.e. the commit that your current checked out branch is on.

```
git checkout -b origin/BRANCH
```

This creates a new *local* branch called `origin/BRANCH` based on your current commit. This is, at best, likely to cause you some confusion and doesn't sound like it's what you want at all.

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout` switches to some branch, it does not fetch it from remote repository. `git checkout -b` also creates the branch. To retrieve a branch from remote repository, use [`git fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html).

Comment: Aaah, so I should run `git fetch origin` before `git checkout -b BRANCH origin/BRANCH` in that cases. Thanks, this solved my problem. (I did misunderstand meaning of *fetch*)

Comment: Yes. In newer versions of git, the latter can be shortened to just `git checkout BRANCH`.

Comment: but not for other remotes (not origin)